# How can I shorten `git checkout` to `git co`?

Tags: git

I want to shorten `git checkout master` to `git co master`.

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases. BTW, this is unrelated to Ruby or Rails.

Comment: `git config --global alias.co checkout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command:

```
git config --global alias.co checkout
```

will create a git alias to do that. It will add the following entry into your global ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
```

Comment: how can i shorten the command like "checkout -b" to create a new branch